# Displaying images from array of objects fails when mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm learning ReactJS and I'm trying to display a list of socials from an array of objects just like so :

```
const baseUrl = "./";
export const SocialData = [
    {
        platform: "Linkedin",
        link: "https://www.linkedin.com/in//",
        icon: baseUrl + "linkedin.png",
    },
    {
        platform: "Github",
        link: "https://github.com/",
        icon: baseUrl + "github.png",
    },
];
```

Then in my component I would display it like this :

```
import { SocialData } from "../../data/social";
import "./socials.css";

function Socials() {
  const data = SocialData;
  return <div className="social-contact"> 
{/*     <img src={require('./linkedin.png')}/>
 */}  {
      data.map((item) => {
          return (
          <a href={item.link} key={item.platform}>
            <div className="social-icon-div">
              <img src={ require(item.icon) } className="social-icon" />
            </div>
          </a>
          )
      })}
    </div>;
}
```

The commented image works just fine, yet when I'm trying to do the same in my map it says and throw this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './linkedin.png'
> at webpackEmptyContext (socials|sync:2:1)
> at Socials.js:14:1
> at Array.map ()
> at Socials (Socials.js:7:1)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)

I've tried to put the require in the data directly, it does the same.
I also tried

> <img src={require( "" + props.src )} alt={props.imageAlt} />

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171142/importing-image-dynamically-react-js-require-img-path-cannot-find-module) but nothing did the job.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the `baseUrl` is correct? The path is relative to the directory the component is in, putting it as `'./linkedin.png'` implies that your image files are in the same folder as `Socials.jsx`

Comment: @Andrew yes it is in the same folder, and as I said when I simply do `<img src={require('./linkedin.png')}/>` in my `Socials.js`, it works and the image is displayed, that's why I'm having trouble finding the reason.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty late to the party but I just ran across the same problem and the only way I figured out how to fix it was saving the image, then importing it as a variable, then using that variable as a template literal for the value of the Link property.

```
For example:

import linkedinImg from "./img/linkedIn.png"

import githubPng from "./img/github.png"

export const SocialData = [
    {
        platform: "Linkedin",
        link: "https://www.linkedin.com/in//",
        icon: `${linkedinImg}`,
    },
    {
        platform: "Github",
        link: "https://github.com/",
        icon: `${githubImg}`,
    },
];
```

then it works when you use it in

```
<a href={item.link} key={item.platform}>
```

downside to this is I downloaded the img to my computer but I was doing that anyways. Hope this helps anyone down the line.